# Undefined control sequence \chapter

Tags: latex, pdflatex

Hello I'm new in Latex.

I was trying to write my thesis, using the MasterDoctoralClass.cls.

This is my main.tex:

```
\documentclass[
11pt, 
english, 
singlespacing,
headsepline
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{mathpazo} 

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} )

\addbibresource{example.bib} 

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGIN SETTINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, 
    inner=2.5cm, 
    outer=3.8cm, 
    bindingoffset=.5cm, 
    top=1.5cm,
    bottom=1.5cm
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\thesistitle{Title Thesis} 
\supervisor{Prof. X \textsc{Y} \\ Dr. Z \textsc{W}}
\degree{Master of Science in  Electronic Engineering} 
\author{Name \textsc{Surname}}

\subject{Electronic Engineering} 
\keywords{} 
\university{{Università}} 
\department{{Department of Information Engineering, Electronics and Telecommunications}} 
\group{{Master of Science in Electronic Engineering}} 
\faculty{{Faculty of Information Engineering, Informatics and Statistics}} 

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} 
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname}
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} 
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter 

\pagestyle{plain} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{logo.jpg}
\end{center}

\begin{center}

\vspace*{.01\textheight}
\textsc{\Large Master Thesis}\\[1cm]

\HRule \\[0.4cm] 
{\huge \bfseries \ttitle\par}\vspace{0.4cm} 
\HRule \\[1.5cm] 

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
\href{}{\authorname} 
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
{\supname} 
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[2cm]

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{logo2.jpg}\hfill\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo3.jpg}
\end{center}

\vspace*{1.5cm}

\groupname\\\deptname\\[1.5cm] 

\vfill

\rule{3cm}{1pt}\\
{\large \today}\\[4cm] 
%\includegraphics{Logo} 

\vfill
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}    
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   QUOTATION PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vspace*{0.2\textheight}

\begin{flushright}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{5cm} 
\itshape\enquote{Something}\\[0.3cm]
\end{flushright}
\hfill Name
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abstract}
\addchaptertocentry{\abstractname} 
The Thesis Abstract is written here (and usually kept to just this page). The page is kept centered vertically so can expand into the blank space above the title too\ldots
\end{abstract}
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{acknowledgements}
\addchaptertocentry{\acknowledgementname} 
The acknowledgments and the people to thank go here, don't forget to include your project advisor\ldots
\end{acknowledgements}
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LIST OF CONTENTS/FIGURES/TABLES PAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents 

\listoffigures 

\listoftables 
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABBREVIATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abbreviations}{ll} %

\textbf{LAH} & \textbf{L}ist \textbf{A}bbreviations \textbf{H}ere\\
\textbf{WSF} & \textbf{W}hat (it) \textbf{S}tands \textbf{F}or\\

\end{abbreviations}
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PHYSICAL CONSTANTS/OTHER DEFINITIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{constants}{lr@{${}={}$}l}      
Speed of Light & $c_{0}$ & \SI{2.99792458e8}{\meter\per\second} (exact)\\   
\end{constants}
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SYMBOLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{symbols}{lll} 

$a$ & distance & \si{\meter} \\
$P$ & power & \si{\watt} (\si{\joule\per\second}) \\
%Symbol & Name & Unit \\

\addlinespace     
$\omega$ & angular frequency & \si{\radian} \\

\end{symbols}
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEDICATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\dedicatory{For my family} 
\end{document}  
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - CHAPTERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter 

\pagestyle{thesis} 

\include{Chapters/Introduction}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter1}
```

If I compile main.tex (with PDFLatex, I also did it with Latex and PDFTex) it doesn't return me any error, but when I look at the PDF it doesn't print the Introduction. 
So I was watching to the Introduction.tex:

```
% Chapter 1

\chapter{Chapter Title Here} % Main chapter title

\label{Chapter1} % For referencing the chapter elsewhere, use \ref{Chapter1} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Define some commands to keep the formatting separated from the content  \newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textbf{#1}} \newcommand{\tabhead}[1]{\textbf{#1}} \newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}} \newcommand{\file}[1]{\texttt{\bfseries#1}} \newcommand{\option}[1]{\texttt{\itshape#1}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Welcome and Thank You} Welcome to this \LaTeX{} Thesis Template, a beautiful and easy to use template for writing a thesis using the \LaTeX{} typesetting system.

If you are writing a thesis (or will be in the future) and its subject is technical or mathematical (though it doesn't have to be), then creating it in \LaTeX{} is highly recommended as a way to make sure you can just get down to the essential writing without having to worry over formatting or wasting time arguing with your word processor.

\LaTeX{} is easily able to professionally typeset documents that run to hundreds or thousands of pages long. With simple mark-up commands, it automatically sets out the table of contents, margins, page headers and footers and keeps the formatting consistent and beautiful. One of its main strengths is the way it can easily typeset mathematics, even \emph{heavy} mathematics. Even if those equations are the most horribly twisted and most difficult mathematical problems that can only be solved on a super-computer, you can at least count on \LaTeX{} to make them look stunning.
```

And if I complie it I have some errors:

```
Undefined control sequence \chapter
Missing \begin{document}. \chapter{C
Undefined control sequence \section
```

I tryed to put the \begin{document} but I still have the same errors on the undefined control sequence and other errors like

```
The font size command \normalisize si not defined:there is probably something wrong with the class file.
```

Can someone help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: Where can we find `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls`? That sure has information on whether you can use `\chapter` or not.

Comment: @Werner, it is one of the standard templates [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If on line 13 you remove the `)` and move the `\end{document}` statement on line 183 to the end of the main, it will compile properly.